# LinkedList print and moving elements to another LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list

From list first I should do LinkedList and put elements into it (I did that). From that list I have to move all not string elements (integers) to another LinkedList and print them also.

Initialisation:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0

   def append(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        last = self.head
        while(last.next):
            last = last.next
        last.next = new_node 
 
def Lista(lista):
    linked = LinkedList()
    for element in lista:
        linked.append(element)
    return linked
```

Function for print and function(izdvoji) to move elements to another linkedlist:

```
def ispis(self):
    temp = self.head
    while (temp):
        print (temp.data)
        temp = temp.next
    print("------")

def izdvoji(self):
    linked = LinkedList()
    temp = self.head
    while(temp):
        if isinstance (temp.data, str):
            linked.append(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next //edited
        else:
            temp = temp.next

if __name__ == '__main__':
    L = Lista([33, "asp","oop1",5,21,"python",2,"c++"])
    ispis(izdvoji(L))
    ispis(L)
```

Result must be:

asp,oop1,python,c++

33,5,21,2

Sorry for long code but I want you to see it.

Edit function:

```
def izdvoji(linkedLista):
    linked = LinkedList()
    temp = linkedLista.head
    while(temp != None):
        if isinstance (temp.data, str):
            linked.append(temp.data)
        temp = temp.next
   
    temp = linkedLista.head
    while(temp != None):
        if temp == linkedLista.head and isinstance (temp.data, str):
            linkedLista.head = temp.next
            print(temp.data)
    
        if temp.next != None and isinstance (temp.next.data, str): 
            temp.next = temp.next.next
           
        temp = temp.next
    return linked
```

Output:

asp,oop1, python,c++,

---

33, oop1, 5, 21, 2,

Comment: What issue are you facing? What is the current output?

Comment: Infinite loop, I tried to create another linkedlist. I'm not sure If this is the right approach.

Comment: In `def izdvoji(self):` if it's a string you don't update `temp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print function accepts an `end` parameter which defaults to `"\n"`. You can it to be `", "` to print your list.

To move your nodes from one list to another you need to do two steps

1. Copy the node to new list
2. Delete the node from old list

You did not have a delete method to handle that so I had to write delete method myself.

**Delete method for linked list**

```
    def delete(self, node_data):
        temp = self.head

        # If list is empty
        if temp is None:
            return

        # If the head need to be removed
        if temp.data == node_data:
            self.head = temp.next
            return

        # Iterate over the list and stops when the next node is our required node
        while temp is not None and temp.next.data != node_data:
            temp = temp.next

        # if temp is none that means we reached the end of list
        if temp is None:
            return

        # removing the node
        temp.next = temp.next.next
```

```
def ispis(linked_list):
    temp = linked_list.head
    while (temp):
        print(temp.data, end=", ")
        temp = temp.next
    print("\n------")
```

**Output:**

```
33, asp, oop1, 5, 21, python, 2, c++, 
------
```

As far as copying goes. You forgot to update the temp when the if condition was true. Technically you don't need else here as well. You also need to return the list after moving the elements which you are not doing.

```
def izdvoji(linked_list):
    linked = LinkedList()
    temp = linked_list.head
    while temp:
        if isinstance(temp.data, str):
            linked.append(temp.data) # Copy node to new list
            linked_list.delete(temp.data) # delete from old list
        temp = temp.next
    return linked
```

**Output:**

```
asp, oop1, python, c++, 
------
33, 5, 21, 2, 
------
```

**Main Code:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    L = Lista([33, "asp","oop1",5,21,"python",2,"c++"])
    ispis(izdvoji(L))
    ispis(L)
```

Note: By convention self is only used for to refer the attributes and methods of the class. `izdvoji` and `ispis` are not class methods. So using self here makes no sense.

Comment: But output in second row should be only numbers.

Comment: The second row is the original list. @BillGejc The first row is from moving the elements.

Comment: @BillGejc Added the code for main so it is clear what is happening.

Comment: But I need output like this: 

asp,oop1,python,c++

33,5,21,2

Comment: First row string, second row numbers

Comment: You need to implement a delete method that deletes the node from the original list. @BillGejc

Comment: I cannot change main part

Comment: The only thing I change was give the variable better name so it is easy to understand. It is doing pretty much the same thing. @BillGejc

Comment: @BillGejc It should work now. I added delete method. Learn how the method works. If you have question. Ask here.